# Invisible data in hdf5 database (with Python / Pandas / ViTables)

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a hdf5 database which causes me some troubles.

It should contains 3,000 tables with 6 columns (integer and float) plus an index (date) and a variable number of rows (from 100 to 10,000,000).

Since yesterday, when I 'look' at the database using ViTables, I miss thousands of tables. I use to be able to see them in ViTables. But the data are still there : I can still access them through Pandas.

The data are organized as follow: `type/source/id`

For instance, I can retrieve both id1 and id2 using:

```
 with pd.get_store(HDF_DATABASE) as store:
     print store['type1/source1/id1']
     print store['type2/source2/id2']
```

But from ViTables, I cannot see `type2/source2/id2`.

Furthermore, `> print store` will list `type1/source1/id1` but not `type2/source2/id2`.

Any advice on how I can fix these 'invisible' data tables ?

EDIT:

- Typos
- Windows 7 32bit / Python 2.7.5 / Pandas 0.12.0 (and other
  versions in the past)
- ptdump file: http://pastebin.com/7mB6bT2T
- as one could expect, I obfuscated type source id
- it looks like the data are not referenced anymore, but still there as long as the database is not ptrepack-ed.

EDIT2:

- I fully lost the original database: I cannot access it anymore. The format is not recognised anymore.
- This statement (and similar others) used to insert new data returns a `NaturalNameWarning` warning : `store.append('equity/bloomberg/4615238QCN_Equity', df)`. It is not respecting the Natural Naming requirement which generates a warning. This might be linked to the encountered issue.

Comment: what version of pandas? Did you do anything yesterday to the file? can you show ``ptdump -av <filename>`` and show the sections for id1 and id2 (you may need to redirect as it will show data on all the nodes)

Comment: @Jeff I use `Pandas 0.12.0` but I used other versions in the past (as you can see in the ptdump file). Please find a link to the dump [here](http://pastebin.com/7mB6bT2T). As you can see, there is no mention of source2 and id2, even though and `store['type2/source2/id2']` still works fine.

Comment: Can you post a link to your file? You can try ``ptrepack in.h5 out.h5`` and see if the problem persists in the new output.

Comment: With`ptrepack in.h5 out.h5`, I cannot access `store['type2/source2/id2']` anymore. The size of `out.h5` is roughly half the size of `in.h5`. The file original file is 250GB and cannot be shared (I bought the data but cannot distribute them). Plus if I delete most of the data and ptrepack it so I can share it online, the issue is not anumore visible.

Comment: ok...just as FYI storing this many tables in a single HDF5 file is not usually a good idea. Are you trying to writing this concurrently by any chance? Its possible you have exceeded the meta data limits and/or had groups rewritten somehow. What operations are you doing on the tables?

Comment: Noted. I do not write concurrently to the file. The problem appeared after I added another 1000+ tables to h5 file. At some point, I got a lot of warnings saying the 'type/source/id' string did not respect some regex which was actually not true. Once the loading finished, I noticed the issue.

Comment: ahh...a ``NaturalNameWarning``?

Comment: yes, this one: NaturalNameWarning: object name is not a valid Python identifier: XXX; it does not match the pattern ``^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$``; you will not be able to use natural naming to access this object; using ``getattr()`` will still work, though NaturalNameWarning ). A typical name was `'my_type\mysource\id_01_01'` which seems fine to me.

Comment: that's the issue; these are 'invalid' in PyTables, see [here](http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/helper_classes.html?highlight=naturalna#tables.NaturalNameWarning). My test for this is a node that is names ``node()`` which 'works' but is a bit odd. I am not sure what ``ptrepack`` actually does with these (e.g. I have never tried to use them), so its possible it doesn't write them out correctly. I also don't think HDFStore prints them correctly (again have not had any demand for it! will check).

Comment: At this point, you should create a new set of files, going thru all of the names (which since you cannot get via ``keys()`` you will have to 'generate' them), select them out and write to a new file. (I don't know why those are showing the NaturalNameWarning either, looks ok to me).

Answer (score 0):

Sample session

```
In [1]: store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

In [2]: store['node()'] = Series(np.arange(10))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/path.py:99: NaturalNameWarning: object name is not a valid Python identifier: 'node()'; it does not match the pattern ``^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$``; you will not be able to use natural naming to access this object; using ``getattr()`` will still work, though
  NaturalNameWarning)

In [3]: store
Out[3]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df                frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->11,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[A,B])
/node()            series       (shape->[10])                                                   

In [4]: store.keys()
Out[4]: ['/df', '/node()']

In [5]: store['node()/foo'] = Series(np.arange(10))

In [6]: store.keys()
Out[6]: ['/df', '/node()', '/node()/foo']

In [7]: store
Out[7]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df                    frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->11,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[A,B])
/node()                series       (shape->[10])                                                   
/node()/foo            series       (shape->[10])                                                   

In [8]: store['my_type\mysource\id_01_01'] = Series(np.arange(10))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tables/path.py:99: NaturalNameWarning: object name is not a valid Python identifier: 'my_type\\mysource\\id_01_01'; it does not match the pattern ``^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$``; you will not be able to use natural naming to access this object; using ``getattr()`` will still work, though
  NaturalNameWarning)

In [9]: store
Out[9]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df                                   frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->11,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[A,B])
/my_type\mysource\id_01_01            series       (shape->[10])                                                   
/node()                               series       (shape->[10])                                                   
/node()/foo                           series       (shape->[10])                                                   

In [10]: store.keys()
Out[10]: ['/df', '/my_type\\mysource\\id_01_01', '/node()', '/node()/foo']

In [11]: store['my_type/mysource/id_01_01'] = Series(np.arange(10))

In [12]: store
Out[12]: 
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: test.h5
/df                                   frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->11,ncols->2,indexers->[index],dc->[A,B])
/my_type\mysource\id_01_01            series       (shape->[10])                                                   
/node()                               series       (shape->[10])                                                   
/node()/foo                           series       (shape->[10])                                                   
/my_type/mysource/id_01_01            series       (shape->[10])
```

The problem is the identifier 'my_type\mysource\id_01_01` is not doing what you think it is, it 'looks' like a file path. You need the backslashes, not forward slashes (as they are architecture dependent). In theory though this will work (but to avoid the warnings, you might want to change these names).

Comment: I am not sure to understand here, I need forward slashes '/' not '\' which is what I did? (I corrected one typo where I put '\' instead of '/').

Comment: the ``\`` backslashes (sorry) are an invalid character in the name. They don't create a hierarchical group (if that was your intention). I also don't think PyTables deals with them in ptrepack (though not sure on this point). I would simply avoid them. Using ``/`` creates hierarchical (tree-like) nodes. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I only used forward slashes in my code, and I was able to see hierarchical groups fine in ViTables. I got the `NaturalNameWarning` warnings using forward slashes only. Ideally, I would like to recover the un-referenced data (worst case, I have an up-to-date back up) and undertstand what went wrong.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the issue, I notice that this statement returns a NaturalNameWarning warning : `store.append('equity/bloomberg/4615238QCN_Equity', df)`. Why?

Comment: AFAIK the problem is starting with a number, it is not a valid identifier

Comment: You are correct! Do you think that can explain why I lost access to half of the database (including tables with valid identifiers)? If yes, pyTables should raise an `Error`, not a `Warning`, right?

Comment: no, they are technically valid, but you have to access them using ``getattr`` and not by name, e.g. ``root.foo`` is ok, but ``root.4615238..`` is NOT. I am not sure the behavior is really defined. I think they they allow it, but since ptrepack can't see them it might be problematicc. If you cann reproduce the problem then feel free to report to PyTables. I think you are trying to store too many tables (nothing to do with size of a particular table, that is effectively unlimited). BUT their are meta data limits per nodes and such. It might work, but in your case is not.

Comment: To be accurate, ptrepack used to see them, and stopped to see them and valid others at some point. Actually, after a few hours playing around this issue, ptrepack stopped seeing anything. Now, I cannot even connect to the original store. I am now creating a new store from scratch with valid names only. Finger crossed it will not happen again. @Jeff, thanks for your much appreciated help!